# Excel Output Loop results to a new cell with each line of the Loop

Tags: excel, vba, new-operator

I am new to Excel Macros and I am trying to to use a Countif function to determine the number of times a "string" appears within an array (c1:I100). Then output this result as an Integer into a Cell on a separate sheet. There are 7 different "strings" I want to count in a loop and output to a new cell within the same column as the first output for each new "string" that is counted.  This is what I have and it causes excel to freeze after filling all output cells with the first counted string value.

```
Sub LayerIssue_CountIf()
Dim SubRange As Range
Dim Output1, Output2, Output3, Output4, Output5, Output6, Output7, Output8 As Range
Dim Lookupname As String

Set SubRange = Range("C1:I100")
Set Output1 = Sheet4.Range("C2")
Set Output2 = Sheet4.Range("C3")
Set Output3 = Sheet4.Range("C4")
Set Output4 = Sheet4.Range("C5")
Set Output5 = Sheet4.Range("C6")
Set Output6 = Sheet4.Range("C7")
Set Output7 = Sheet4.Range("C8")
Set Output8 = Sheet4.Range("C9")

y = 2

Do While y = 2
  If Cells(y, 3) = "" Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .5"
  Output1 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 3 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .4"
  Output2 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 4 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .3"
  Output3 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 5 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .2"
  Output4 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 6 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .1"
  Output5 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 7 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .05"
  Output6 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
  
  ElseIf y = 8 Then
  Lookupname = "Jans .01"
  Output7 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, Lookupname)
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: In your code, y = 2 and isn't changed thereafter. Therefore the loop continued forever. Also note that only `Output8` is declared as a range. All the others in the same line are declared as Variants by default.

Comment: Do I have to put the list of outputs in brackets to get them all to be defined as a range?  Where would I change y = 2 to y = y+1?

Comment: There is no way. Best, declare one variable per line. If you must have several in one line you can omit subsequent `Dim` but must declare the data type for each, like `Dim Output1 As Range, Output2 As Range` except you would declare one array by that name as I demonstrate below. Change y with `y = y + 1` or in a *For ... Next* loop as demonstrated below. In the loop the `Next i` command advances the counter.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't use so many IFs in VBA programming. *Select Case* would be the weapon of choice. But if the result can be determined without a condition that will be more efficient. Also, consider using arrays instead of multiple variables.

Your code isn't entirely clear on which you want to do with the output. However, the procedure below does show the approach you should take.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LayerIssue_CountIf()

    Dim SubRange        As Range
    Dim Output(1 To 7)  As Long
    Dim LookupName()    As Variant
    Dim i               As Long                 ' loop counter: Output index
    
    ' The array will be 0-based. To match Output() 0 is added and left unused.
    LookupName = Array(0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01)
    Set SubRange = Range("C2:I100")
    
    ' count from 1 to 7
    For i = LBound(Output) To UBound(Output)
        Output(i) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SubRange, "Jans " & Format(LookupName(i), ".0#"))
    Next i
    
    ' cell C3 is included in SubRange. Not sure you want to write there.
    With Cells(2, "B")
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Resize(UBound(Output), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Output)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  There are so many different commands that I dont know of.  I have been at this for a week.  I will  be able to learn a lot from this code.